# Issues with onRequest function erring Not all code paths return a value

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I have the following onReqeust cloud function that is erroring with

> Argument of type '(req: Request, res: Response) => Promise<Response | undefined>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(req: Request, resp: Response) => void | Promise'.
> Type 'Promise<Response | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'void | Promise'.
> Type 'Promise<Response | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Promise'.
> Type 'Response | undefined' is not assignable to type 'void'.
> Type 'Response' is not assignable to type 'void'.ts(2345)
> Not all code paths return a value.ts(7030)

what could be causing this issue ?

```js
// Note: Migrate data from one collection to another after a sub update.....
export const stripeDataMigrationWebhook = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // 1. set signiture header
    const signature = req.headers['stripe-signature'];
    // 2. get endpoint secret
    const endpointSecret = functions.config().stripe.data_migration_webhook;
    // 3. format the body (rawBody)
    const rawBody = req.rawBody.toString();
    // 4. construct the incoming event
    const event: StripeWebhookEvent = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(rawBody, signature, endpointSecret);
    // 5. handle the event
    if (event.type === 'invoice.paid') {
      const invoicePaidObject: StripeInvoice = event.data.object;
      // A. Get the email from the event
      const email = invoicePaidObject.customer_email;
      // B. Get the paind Subscription id so we can get the it from firestore
      const subscriptionId = invoicePaidObject.subscription;
      // B. Get the user from auth by email from the event
      const userObject = admin.auth().getUserByEmail(email!);

      let currentUserData: {
        userType: null | UsersTypes;
        uid: null | string;
        stripeRole: null | string;
      } = { userType: null, uid: null, stripeRole: null };

      // C. set the current user data using the userObject
      await userObject.then((user: UserRecord) => {
        currentUserData = { userType: user.customClaims?.userType, uid: user.uid, stripeRole: user.customClaims?.stripeRole };
      });

      const userType = currentUserData.userType;
      const uid = currentUserData.uid;

      if (userType && uid) {
        try {
          const customerSubscriptionsDoc = await firestore.collection('data-customers').doc(uid).collection('subscriptions').doc(subscriptionId).get();
          // Note: Check if the doc exists
          if (!customerSubscriptionsDoc.exists) {
            // Note: response with 404 indicating that the resource does not exist on the server.
            return res.status(404).send('Webhook Error: could not get the subscription doc.');
          }

          const price = customerSubscriptionsDoc.data()?.price;
          const parts = price.split('/');
          const productId = parts[1];
          const verdict = shouldMigrateData(productId, userType);

          // Note : mainDoc ====> sharedDoc Process
          if (verdict === 'upgrade') {
            // try {
            //   // A. Get the main doc of the user.
            //   const mainDocSnapshot = await firestore.collection(dynamicCollectionName(userType, 'mainDoc')).doc(uid).get();
            //   // Note: Check if the doc exists
            //   if (!mainDocSnapshot.exists) {
            //     return res.status(404).send('Webhook Error: could not get the main doc.');
            //   }
            //   const data = mainDocSnapshot.data() as MainDocAthletePersonalTrainer;
            //   migrateDateMainToShared(userType, data, uid);
            // } catch (error) {
            //   webhookErrorHandling(res, 400, error);
            // }
          }

          // Note : sharedDoc ====> mainDoc Process
          if (verdict === 'downgrade') {
            // try {
            //   // A. Get the main doc of the user.
            //   const sharedDocSnapshot = await firestore.collection(dynamicCollectionName(userType, 'sharedDoc')).doc(uid).get();
            //   // Note: Check if the doc exists
            //   if (!sharedDocSnapshot.exists) {
            //     return res.status(404).send('Webhook Error: could not get the shared doc.');
            //   }
            //   const data = sharedDocSnapshot.data() as SharedDoc;
            //   migrateDateSharedToMain(userType, data, uid);
            // } catch (error) {
            //   webhookErrorHandling(res, 400, error);
            // }
          }
        } catch (error) {
          webhookErrorHandling(res, 400, error);
        }
      }
    }
    // 6. send response
    res.status(200).send('Success');
  } catch (error) {
    webhookErrorHandling(res, 400, error);
  }
});
```